# Converting PNG to Bitmap with transparency using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap, directx

I have a transparent png image. I read that file using opencv. Then I am converting it to bitmap as follows.

```
Mat image = imread("fruit.png", -1);
BYTE * rawdata = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(image.data);
m_pBitmap->CopyFromMemory(NULL, rawdata, image.cols * 4);
m_pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(m_pBitmap);
```

But after converting some images show some transparency problems... Same as in this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3288/problem-reading-png-with-transparency-layer/)  and the image is not showing full. But when we save that Mat image using imwrite there is no problem.
So the problems I am facing are

1. Transparency of some images are lost.
2. The full image data is not showing.
   [image: input image]
   [image: output image]

Comment: The link you referenced seems to be a problem with  `imshow` rather than with the image itself, can you edit to show how did you initialized your `Bitmap` variable ? this bitmap class in the android one?

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the image format within OpenCV, since different libraries have their own decoding and representing methods.

Try the following codes:

```
Mat image = imread("fruit.png", -1);
Mat image_bmp;
image.convertTo(image_bmp, CV_8UC3);
imwrite("fruit.bmp", image_bmp);
```

You can specify in which format you want to save your image by `.bmp` or `.jpg` in the filename.

The result looks like this (after resize of course):

[image]

Comment: Judging by the users sample code, he doesn't mean bitmap files, but a bitmap class in c++... I think it is the android bitmap class.

Comment: @api55 ...well in that case, personally, I think declaring Mat with `jint *buf = env->GetIntArrayElements()` and handling bitmap as int array in c++ is more convenient:)

Comment: sure, it may be more convenient (however i prefer to stick with the uchar representation of opencv), but still it doesn't solve the problem ... I think he is using a different representation for the bytes or something in that direction, but not sure until he answers back

Comment: @JohnHany I need transparent image after conversion and I am not talkking about bitmap class in DirectX.

Comment: @api55 What I need is to convert Mat to id1d2bitmap

Comment: @Neeraj I'm not familiar with the `id1d2bitmap` you're using. My best guess is that what you need is maintaining two copies of a bitmap, one with 3-channel for displaying and the other with 4-channel for data manipulating. If result of 4-channel `id1d2bitmap` is unpredictable as well, you may need another single-channel `id1d2bitmap` to represent transparency independently. BTW, are you sure you're using the correct one? Because there is a `2bit` in `id1d2bitmap`...

Comment: @Neeraj I understand that, but how do initialize m_bitmap then? opencv data representation is something like b_1 g_1 r_1 a_1 b_2 g_2 r_2 a_2 .... so if you initialized the variable wrong it will give you weird results....

Comment: @api55 m_pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
   rtProps,
   D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hWnd, size),
   &m_pRenderTarget)
m_pRenderTarget->CreateBitmap(
   size,
   D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)),
   &m_pBitmap
   );

Comment: @Neeraj can you try with different type of alpha mode like `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT`and also, can you try to use a more direct approach like this [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371800(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @api55 D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT already tried. We got exception on m_pBitmap->CopyFromMemory(NULL, rawdata, image.cols * 4); 
When we tried with loading image from WIC component to this bitmap it is working as transparent. 
Only reading byte from cv::Mat to Bitmap is not transparen ..

Comment: @Neeraj ...then no need sticking to opencv, at least not with image decoding part, right? I googled "opencv direct2d" and very few results supporting combining them together. Maybe opencv is not No. 1 choice for a Direct2D-friendly port;)